# BGE - remember position after action

Tags: animation, game-engine

In the BGE I need - remember location after action. I have button - when I press - character do a step forward. I want make when the another press character begin step from a new position, after old step.

[image]
http://joxi.ru/KAxeW4jcW7qgr8

just remember this new position after step.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing, but maybe you should rebuild your animation so that the step is taken in place, and you should move the armature instead.

If you dont't want to do this, then you need to add a python script to move your object to the exact position where you animated step ends... You must get the object's world position and increment it by whatever distance it travels in your animation. The script is only activated at the end of your animation... you can use the frame property on the action actuator to control this.

hope this helps
Nuno Estanqueiro

Comment: thank you very much, I try to rebuild and add movement for cube parent but it's not work for me, I miss something. can you see this logical and tell more detailed what wrong https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8AB9z2m-RC1ak1TdVNoc2RBREk/view?usp=sharing
it's without cube version

Comment: Separate movement from animation. To let the game work, you need motion only. The animation is "just" to make it look like nice. Basically: the animation is not the cause of the motion.

Comment: Thank you, Monster! you here too))

but separating animation and parenting for cube give not smothly effect. legs move always. 
I solve this http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?387126-NEED-HELP-BGE-and-buttons-for-animation-remaining-location&p=2975543&viewfull=1#post2975543

but not smooth animation effect a little dissapointing